# How do I match Bootstrap styles with multiple html files?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am working in a group project at school and just started to learn html/css/bootstrap.

We have to complete individually html files which represent web pages of our website, and then apply our css style sheets to groups of web pages.

The professor also told us to learn bootstrap optionally. I just went through most of the bootstrap tutorial on w3schools. However, I don't think I understand how I can apply bootstrap as a group?

From my understanding, bootstrap mainly uses classes to style elements (correct me if i'm wrong), in this case, how would I apply the way I style one web page to another?

Is it the case that the 'stylesheet' in this case is simply bootstrap, and we re-write the classes for every web page html file?

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The classes are pre-written, so you don't have to re-write them again. Just add the `class`  attribute to any HTML element you want to style, with the corresponding value.

Comment: So if I have more than one web page for my website, I just need to add the bootstrap href to all of them, and individually add the class attributes to the elements inside the webpages in a way to make them match?

Comment: Yes, if you want to style your elements differently, then you have to individually add the class attributes to the elements

Comment: If this helped you, please help me by upvoting me on answer and on my comments.